# Finding the equation of a line given a line perpendicular to it and the area of a triangle with the axes

Tags: analytic-geometry

A line $l$ is perpendicular to the line $3x-4y+18=0$ and the area of triangle bounded by the line $l$ with the co ordinate axes is $6$ sq. units, find the equation of $l$.

My Approach,

Since the line $l$ is perpendicular to the line $3x-4y+18=0$, its equation must be $$4x+3y+k=0$$. But I don't know the point through which this equation passes. Then, how do I find the value of $k$.

I got stuck at here. Please help me to complete.

Comment: The line cuts the axis $OX$ when $y=0.$ So, the cut point is $(-k/4,0).$ It cuts the $OY$ axis when $x=0,$ that is, at point $(0,-k/3).$ With the origin you have a right triangle. Make its area equal to $6.$

Comment: #mfl, how did you get those points? Please interpret clearly.

Comment: $k=12$. I think

Comment: #mfl, What do you mean by 'rectangle triangle'?

Comment: @Ivan Abraham, $k=+/- 12$. But how did you get?

Comment: I meant a right triangle.

Comment: When $y=0$ you get $x$ intercept. That is $-k/3$. Similarly when $x=$ is zero you get the other intercept which like pointed out above is $-k/4$. Then use half base times height. $k^2/24=6$.

Comment: But, what would the figure look like? I am unable to make the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle of area $6$ is determined by three points:

- The origin of coordinates, $(0,0),$
- The cut point of the line $l$ and the $x$-axis, and
- The cut point of the line $l$ and the $y$-axis.

Since the equation of $x$-axis is $y=0$ we solve

$$\left\{\begin{align}y & =0 \\ 4x+3y+k &=0\end{align}\right.$$ to get the cut point $(-k/3,0).$

In a similar way we get the cut point of $l$ and the $y$-axis, getting the point $(0,-k/3).$

So, the area of the right triangle is $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{k}{3}\cdot \frac{k}{4}.$$ If we equal this quantity to $6$ we get that $k=\pm 12.$

Comment: #mfl, could you please provide me the figure, too?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the picture drawn out as requested apart from the well written answer above.

[image: Graph of equation $4x+3y+12==0.]